# Can mysqli_insert_id be broken by multiple scripts hitting a database at once?

Tags: php, mysqli

Let's say I have a script that will be run on multiple systems congruently and used to insert a piece of data into a mySQL table that has an AUTO INCREMENTING index. Let's say the script looks something like this:

```
$db = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'db');

$value1 = (Some Value);
$value2 = (Some Other Value);

$query = "INSERT INTO `my_table` (`column1`, `column2`) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2')";
$db->query($query);

// Now I want to grab the index
$session_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);

// Here I will do a bunch of calculations
// ...
// ...
// and get...

$value3 = (Result Of Calculations);

// And now I want to add value3 to the same row in the table so I do:
$query = "UPDATE `my_table` SET `column3`='$value3' WHERE `id`='$session_id'";
$db->query($query);
```

Now my question is if I have 100, or 1000 users running this script simultaneously is it possible that the id's would fall out of sync if the first INSERT on an instance of the script happened before another instance got to the **mysqli_insert_id($db);** call.

If the answer is "Yes this could break the function," please provide a better solution to the above situation.

If the answer is "No this will not break the function," please provide an explanation of why it won't.

I have tested this code on my development machine and it works well however I'm concerned that in production it could potentially fail.

Thank you!

Comment: Nope. _"The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own."_ Documented here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: Note: in PHP, `mysqli_insert_id()` (and all its cousins in PDO and MySQLi) are just thin wrappers around MySQL's native `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function mentioned above so the same rules apply.

Comment: No, as mentioned in the previous comment your code is safe in terms of referential integrity. Just to note that such kind of operation should be wrapped as `TRANSACTION` code because if the `INSERT` Is not successful you should not `UPDATE` any other tables...